# Persisting SignalR chat app to database

Tags: signalr

I have a simple SignalR chat application up and running.

However, I can't find anything about how you can persist the messages users send to a database, bizarrely - even though it would seem like an obvious requirement.

This is because we need a record of what people are saying, and want users who join to see the last few messages.

I have two SignalR books - neither cover this topic (Apress Pro ASP.net SignalR, and the Microsoft Press book SignalR programming).

Google searches return nothing about persisting messages to a database and I've found no samples that do this.

Am I missing something? How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect SignalR book to cover that topic ? Those topics has nothing to do with each other. SignalR is a library for real-time communications. Persistence of data is a separate from SignalR question.

Comment: I know how to persist data - I want to persist data *that people are typing in over SignalR* because it is surely a very common use case. Either way - that is my question.

Comment: You know this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server ?

Comment: Thanks - I saw that - but it's not what I need - they are just using SQL Server to spread a - I guess high traffic - SignalR app across multiple servers using SQL Server to co-ordinate.